# How to capture the number of downloads of a specific file

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a project that involves downloading files. I have been tasked to create a report of how many downloads per file. Here is my code:

reports.py

```
def dataset_download(request):
        download = DataSet.objects.annotate(numdownload=Count('name'),)
        return render(request, "my_admin/dataset_download.html", {"download":download})
```

my models.py

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField()
        purpose = models.TextField()
        temporal_scope = models.TextField()
        taxonomic_scope = models.TextField()
```

my urls.py

```
 path('dataset_download/', reports.dataset_download, name='dataset_download'),
```

and finally my html

```
 {% for d in download %} 
          {% if d.name != "" %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{ d.name }}</td> 
               <td>{{ d.numdownload }}</td>
               <td>
                  <a href="/dataset/?name={{ d.name }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                   <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 
                   View Details
                 </a>
              </td>
              </tr>
        {% endif %} 
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Where does a file get downloaded in the code you're showing us? Where in your code are you keeping track of the number of downloads? What is your code currently doing? And what is different from what you expect?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my question is , i want whenever some one downloads a file, that  event should be counted. in otherwards i want a report on the number of downloads per dataset

Comment: this is my dataset.html where a file gets downloaded

Comment: <a href="/download_data_set/?dataset={{ dataset.id }}" class="btn btn- 
        info btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download 
        DataSet</a>
                  {% endif %}

                  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                              <td>{{ dataset.name }}</td>
                          </tr>

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following Django app to keep track of all of your downloads.

You can go through the documentation here.

https://pypi.org/project/django-download-stats/

Comment: this does not work because im using the latest version of django

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new attribute and method to your model:

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    purpose = models.TextField()
    temporal_scope = models.TextField()
    taxonomic_scope = models.TextField()
    numdownload = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def increment_numdownload(self):
        self.numdownload +=1
        return self.numdownload
```

And call this method whenever download event is loaded.

Comment: how do i call the method

Comment: please help me im new to all of this